# unable to display for loop elements in an alert window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in web development and I am working on a project where I have a product webpage . Now , each product has a quantity ,  a price of 9.99$ and a checkbox if I want to buy it . I have to make a function that when I click a specific image (that appears twice) in my page a pop up window has to appear with all the names of the books I have selected and their respective amount .
ex.

```
    Title : "Book1" Quantity : "4"
    Title : "Book2" Quantity : "1"
```

I have written javascript code and have gotten all the elements perfectly but my problem is how to display them. I have my code down below.
I would appreciate your help with guiding me through this issue. 
Thank you in advance.

```js
function displayinfo() {
    var sum = 0;
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("bought"); //get checkboxes 
    var quantities = document.getElementsByClassName("amn"); //get quantities
    var floatprice = parseFloat("9.99");//all books cost 9.99
    var books = document.getElementsByClassName("p-name"); //get names
    var names = new Array(6); //array of books we bought
    var amounts = new Array(6); //array that displays the amounts of books we bought 
  
    for (var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++) {
      if (boxes[i].checked==true&&quantities[i].value!=null) {
  names[i]=books[i].innerHTML; //add name of book to array 
         amounts[i]=quantities[i].value; // add quantity of book to array
  sum+=quantities[i].value*floatprice; //increase total  
      }
    }  
   
    var sm = document.getElementsByClassName("thesum");
    var str = sum.toString();
   
    for (var e = 0; e < sm.length; e++) {
      sm[e].innerHTML = str;
    }
    
    // an alert function should be placed here to make all the respective elements appear
}
```

```html
//my image and the products I have 

<img src = "IMAGES/shopcart.png" onclick="displayinfo()" class = "cart"  alt = cart/> : <span class = "thesum"> </span> (click to display purchase information)   
 
 
  <div id="p-float">
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\subtle.jpg" alt = subtle_art/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Subtle Art of not giving an F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
       <div class="product">

               <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class="amn"  name = "num" onchange="updatetotal(event)" value = "0"  min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                     <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought"  name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
       </div>
     </div></div>
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\everything.jpg" alt = every/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Everything is <br/> F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
             <div class="product">

               <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class = "amn" onchange="updatetotal(event)" name = "num"   value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                        <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
             </div>

     </div></div>
  
      <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt = deepw/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
             <div class="product">

               <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class="amn" onchange="updatetotal(event)" name = "num"  value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                        <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
       </div>
     </div></div>
    
 
   <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\giant.jpg" alt = gnt/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Awaken the giant within</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
                <div class="product">

                      <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class="amn" onchange="updatetotal(event)" name = "num"  value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
      </div>
     </div></div> 
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\habits.jpg" alt = hbts/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">7 Habits of highly effective people</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
             <div class="product">

               <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class = "amn"  name = "num" onchange="updatetotal(event)" value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                        <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me" /> Buy Me  </div>
              </div>
     </div></div>
      
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\anything.jpg" alt = any/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Achieve anything in 1 year</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
             <div class="product">

                <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class="amn"  name = "num" onchange="updatetotal(event)" value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                         <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
          </div>
     </div></div>
      
  </div>
```

Comment: @FloriBruci there isn't anything wrong with the code . I just don't know how to create an alert box that displays all the selected data.As for bootstrap I haven;t touched it yet

Comment: @FloriBruci I cannot use bootstrap . It's a univeristy project

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a COLLECTION and it does not have innerHTML. `sm.innerHTML = str;` <-- do you see what you did wrong?

Comment: @epascarello it is sm[i].innerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a quick adaptation of my code to your HTML. I removed the `onchange=...` references, as there is no function `updatetotal()` defined.

(I am still ignoring the checkboxes and check the content of the quantity field (class="amn") instead, to decide whether a particular book was chosen or not.)

```js
var floatprice = parseFloat("9.99");//all books cost 9.99
function displayinfo(){
 var count=0,books=[...document.querySelectorAll('.p-float-in')]
  .filter(b=>b.querySelector('.amn').value>0)
  .map(b=>{var amn=+b.querySelector('.amn').value;
           count+=amn;
           return amn+' x '+ b.querySelector('.p-name').textContent.trim()})
 alert('You selected '+books.slice(0,-1).join(', ')
   +(books.length>1?' and ':'')+books.pop()+'.\nAt a price of '
   +floatprice+' they total at '+floatprice*count+'.')
}
```

```html
<div id="p-float">
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\subtle.jpg" alt = subtle_art/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Subtle Art of not giving an F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
       <div class="product">

               <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class="amn"  name = "num" value = "0"  min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                     <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought"  name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
       </div>
     </div></div>
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\everything.jpg" alt = every/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Everything is <br/> F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
             <div class="product">

               <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class = "amn" name = "num"   value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                        <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
             </div>

     </div></div>
  
      <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt = deepw/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
             <div class="product">

               <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class="amn" name = "num"  value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                        <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
       </div>
     </div></div>
    
 
   <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\giant.jpg" alt = gnt/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Awaken the giant within</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
                <div class="product">

                      <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number"  class="amn" name = "num"  value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
      </div>
     </div></div> 
  
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\habits.jpg" alt = hbts/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">7 Habits of highly effective people</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
             <div class="product">

               <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class = "amn"  name = "num" value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                        <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me" /> Buy Me  </div>
              </div>
     </div></div>
      
     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\anything.jpg" alt = any/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Achieve anything in 1 year</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
             <div class="product">

                <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" class="amn"  name = "num" value = "0" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
                         <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" class = "bought" name = "box" value = "buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
          </div>
     </div></div>
      
  </div>
<a href="#" onclick="displayinfo()">got to shopping cart</a>
```

Comment: I have added the html . Could you modify your example for the above code please?